# Firebase TOTP multi-factor authentication enrollment TypeError

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-identity

I am adding TOTP multi-factor authentication to my web app as per the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/totp-mfa) using firebase version 10.8.0.

More specifically, I am following the [enrollment steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/totp-mfa#enroll_users_in_totp_mfa) from the above documentation.

I am able to generate a TOTP secret, and using a QR code, display the secret to the user so that they can enter it into their authenticator app (Steps 1-4 in the docs).

Using the `totpSecret` obtained from the previous step, I then prompt the user to enter the confirmation code `verificationCode` displayed on their authenticator app, and use it to finalize MFA enrollment with the following code (Step 5  in the docs):

```
    const auth = getAuth().currentUser;
    const multiFactorAssertion =
      TotpMultiFactorGenerator.assertionForEnrollment(
        totpSecret,
        verificationCode
      );

    multiFactor(user)
      .enroll(multiFactorAssertion, "mfa_totp")
      .then((res) => {
         // Success
         console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         // Error
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Upon enrollment, the user receives the following error, which looks like it could be a bug within the package:

```
TypeError: this.secret._makeTotpVerificationInfo is not a function
    at TotpMultiFactorAssertionImpl._callee97$ (index-bea2a320.js:18548:1)
    at tryCatch (regeneratorRuntime.js:45:1)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (regeneratorRuntime.js:133:1)
    at Generator.next (regeneratorRuntime.js:74:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:27:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at TotpMultiFactorAssertionImpl.<anonymous> (asyncToGenerator.js:19:1)
    at TotpMultiFactorAssertionImpl._finalizeEnroll (index-bea2a320.js:18560:1)
    at TotpMultiFactorAssertionImpl._process (index-bea2a320.js:18296:1)
    at MultiFactorUserImpl._callee54$ (index-bea2a320.js:12161:1)
    at tryCatch (regeneratorRuntime.js:45:1)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (regeneratorRuntime.js:133:1)
    at Generator.next (regeneratorRuntime.js:74:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
```

As you can see from the docs, the implementation steps are rather trivial so I suspect that the above error may be due to a bug within the package. Any assistance is appreciated!

**Updated:**
The issue was that when generating the multiFactorAssertion, I was using the totpSecret.secretKey instead of the totpSecret itself.

Hopefully this helps someone else who runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think the mistake is that you passed the `user` to `multiFactor` instead of `auth`

```
const auth = getAuth().currentUser;
const multiFactor = multiFactor(auth);

const multiFactorAssertion = TotpMultiFactorGenerator.assertionForEnrollment(
  totpSecret,
  verificationCode
);

multiFactor
  .enroll(multiFactorAssertion, "mfa_totp")
  .then((res) => {
    // Enrollment Success
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Enrollment Error
    console.log(error);
  });
```